# Восстановить доступ к телеграмм-аккаунту

Tags: telegram, администрирование

Долго не заходил в десктоп-версию телеграмма. Поэтому произошёл автоматический логаут и требует ввести телефон для отправки кода. Можно ли получить доступ к аккаунту, **если нет телефона**, указанного при логине (в принципе не существует такого номера, а не потерян/украден)? Может по локальным файлам как-то? Какие файлы телеграм проверяет при логине? Или просто сверяет на сервере дату последнего логина и если таймаут превышен, то -аккаунт у человека? Есть ли вариант подтасовать эту дату в таком случае (есть наличие неоткрывавшейся ещё сессии на другой системе, но там тоже долго не заходили)?

Все пароли и номера есть, нет самого телефона и логаут сделал не я, а сам телеграм.

Comment: А как вы получили СМС на несуществующий номер при регистрации?

Comment: Может быть у вас остались где-то открытые сессии на других устройствах? Тогда код подтверждения придет туда, а не по СМС.